# Как поменять заголовок адаптивного меню OPENCART X BOOTSTRAP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, opencart

Как перевести "categories".
в /language - всё переведено
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотреть в шаблон страницы, скорее всего, строка хардкодится там

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ПКМ на элементе -> Посмотреть код элемента (developers tools) -> определите, к какому файлу представления принадлежит данный блок (где не перевело) -> найдите .tpl с этим блоком и проверьте что формирует строку: хардкод или переменная. Если переменная - откройте контроллер этой вьюхи и посмотрите, попадает ли репеменная с переводом в $data.

```
$data['имя_переменной'] = $this->language->get('имя_переменной_на_фронте');
```

Если да - проверьте, какие файлы локализации подключены в данном контролере и в каком файле локализации лежит данный перевод в принципе.

```
$this->load->language('.../...');
```